# React nested Component, arbitrary communication

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

There are many answers regarding react component communication, but seems none of them resolved my problem. Here is my problem's detail. Please help! Thanks in advance.

I'm building a flexible form. The UI is generated by nesting components.

The form data structure could also be nested json objects.

i.e form can have some inputs and sections, sections can have some inputs or sections, and go on.
sections is just UI layout components, doesn't care about data or state.

But input (could be text input, checkbox etc anything to capture data)

The problem I'm facing is any input's validation could depends on any other inputs' value.

i.e inputA has validation expression like formData.inputB >formData.inputA + formData.inputC

But they could also have no dependency at all if you don't give a validation expression.

If I pass the whole formData down the component tree, every time I type in one input, the whole form will rerender.

I have considered redux, but real not sure how redux can help such case. I'm still relative new to react and redux, so I could be wrong.

So what could be a viable solution?

Comment: Do you have some code to show? Or is it still in your head?

Comment: I have no code to show now, I'm evaluating whether react can handle such case or not before give it a deep div.

Comment: what's wrong with re-rendering the form?

Comment: for small form is fine. but once the form grow bigger. you type in one input, then the whole form just re-render simply will hit performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its a common issue when you're modularizing form elements. I have the same problem.

Redux is by far the most controlled solution. All of the components can listen and update the same object simultaneously. But you can also attach functions as props from the parent that you bind to the parent. The function would fetch the state of the parent and update the state like a makeshift store. If you're a good developer, this is possible but neither are simple to do. Good time to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

1. There are various solutions to your problem, but in general it shouldn't even be a problem, because rendering (even of large forms) should be quite effective with React.
2. The core tool for adjusting performance in React is the `shouldComponentUpdate` method of your component classes. If you're smart about what you pass to the individual form fields and then implement `shouldComponentUpdate` properly on them, you should be able to update only when needed. In your particular example, you don't need to pass the full object everywhere.

   You can just pass `value`, `onChange` and `isInvalid` to each field and calculate the validity at the root (where you have access to the full state). Then the `shouldComponentUpdate` of your fields can decide just based on those `props`. (Obviously this is a simplistic example, but as a principle it's sound.)
3. Sure, Redux is another possible solution. If you keep the state in Redux store and only connect each of your fields to the portion of the state it needs, you should be all set. It brings quite a change in architecture though, so you should choose Redux only if you really want it for your app as a whole.